# October CMS backend view pagination

Tags: pagination, octobercms

I'm building a website that contains several thousand records. My backend listview of the items is terribly slow. I can't find out how to apply pagination in this view. There is documentation that states

```
$users = Db::table('tablename')->paginate(15);
```

I just don't know how to implement this code and where to do so.

Answer (score 5):

In your list configuration, specify `recordsPerPage`.
The default is 0, but any other number will activate pagination:

So in `config_list.yaml`, use:

`recordsPerPage: 20`

See also: https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists